# Unable to comment a block of code in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, comments

It seems I'm unable to comment out blocks of code in Android Studio using the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> (on my Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro there's no Numpad and hence no `/` character on its own button).

Pressing the above combination creates a bookmark with the number 7 instead.

Does anyone know a workaround or am I just stuck with `/* *\`?

Comment: I'm actually very surprised there isn't a ' / ' key on your keyboard.
You can usually comment code by using Ctrl-/ or Ctrl-Shift-/

Comment: /*  */ I believe, and on Hungarian layout, the / symbol is Shift+6 (but you can use Ctrl+C Ctrl+V too)

Comment: I am utterly surprised by you saying `there's no Numpad and hence no '/' character on its own button.` a keyboard without `/` is just impossible to imagine. By the way the @jaytj95's answer us right.

Comment: Why are you surprised @Setu?
This is my keyboard and if you can find the / anywhere else than on the 7-key I'll buy you a beer.
[IMG]http://i58.tinypic.com/2vn2h6p.jpg[/IMG]

And again pressing CTRL + shift + 7 (7 to get the /) doesn't work. it makes a bookmark.

Comment: @Kenneth there right there, I can see `/` one your keyboard on number `7`. `Alt Gr + 7` will type `/`.

Comment: @Setu Are you not reading what I'm writing to you?? Shift + 7 makes the ///////////////////////////////// Got it? AltGr + 7 makes the {
Please don't down vote me because of your ignorance

Comment: The answer is.... BADAM! (German keyboard)
Don't look for the "/" (slash) character in the num-pad, look for the division character (got it? yeah, that "hyphen" with one dot on top and one dot underneath. Right, that key on top of the "8". Interpret that key as "/". Then everything works fine: Ctrl+"division" or Ctrl+Shft+"division" add the comments as they should if division symbol were "/".
Funny! :P

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem is that the binding is to the main character on the key, which on your keyboard is <kbd>7</kbd>, not <kbd>/</kbd>. As I commented before, you might want to try if pressing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> works (that is the location of <kbd>/</kbd> on my US International keyboard).

Otherwise, I'd suggest you map it to another combination. I don't have Android Studio, but in IntelliJ IDEA (which has the same foundation as Android Studio) this can be configured under File, Settings, Keymap (Main Menu > Code > Comment with Line Comment) or just search for line comment.

Comment: IntelliJ support team has confirmed that my keyboard layout is not currently supported and that I should remap the hotkey.

CTRL + - hides the code block.

Thank you.

Comment: I cannot believe that only american keyboards are supported… omg this makes me so angry

Comment: @Plot technically the problem is not that "only american keyboards are supported". Mapping of shortcuts happens to the main key value (the value you yet get without any modifier). So if the current shortcut is mapped to a value that is not a main key value, then the shortcut won't work and will need to be remapped; something which is fully supported!

Comment: @Kenneth, maybe you could create an answer for remapping the hotkey.

Answer (score 5):

[Here is the <kbd>/</kbd> key on your Yoga 2 Pro Keyboard.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVvm1.jpg)

You can usually comment code by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>/</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>/</kbd>

Comment: I have a danish keyboard and it looks different that what you're linking too.
Here's my keyboard: [IMG]http://i58.tinypic.com/2vn2h6p.jpg[/IMG]

Comment: I have a Turkish keyboard. CTRL + SHIFT + . worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you have a keyboard driver installed that matches your keyboard.

The lowest symbol on left is the one you normally get when you press the key without also pressing any modifier key.

The symbol above that is the one you normally get when you press that key simultaneously with the `Shift` key.

The symbol to the right is the one you normally get when you press that key simultaneously with the `Alt Gr` (it is the `Alt` key on right hand side) key.

If you are talking about a laptop, and the third symbol is in an a different colour from the other marks on the key, usually in blue, then it is usually obtainable by pressing that key simultaneously with the FN key. See [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fn_key) .

**Example**

In UK laptop keyboards we generally have three symbols on key `4` which are normally `$` on top, `4` on bottom left and `€` on bottom right.

- Only pressing `4` will simply print `4`.
- Pressing `Shift + 4` will print `$`.
- Pressing `Alt Gr + 4` will pring `€`.

**NOTE:**  All of the above is written with assumption that you have the proper keyboard drivers installed on your pc/laptop.

Comment: Thank you.. I know how to use the keyboard.. Wauw.. You set the bar low..
Shift + 7 draws a / on the screen... Therefore CTRL + shift + 7 should enable commenting of code blocks. But it doesn't.
I have linked my keyboard layout further up

Comment: According to the IntelliJ docs CTRL + / or CTRL + shift + / should allow for commenting code blocks..
I can only press CTRL + shift + 7 which should be the equivalent of CTRL + /